# Is it possible to use gevent execution pools with Celery beat?

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat

I have some tasks that I would like to run in a parallel fashion. They are almost 100% IO bound and not cpu intensive (simply making API requests).

I use celery/celerybeat in a Docker environment and have just added `--pool=gevent` to  my docker-compose file, but I must also pass `--beat`.

When I start my app I get the following error:

```
celery.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: -B option doesn't work with eventlet/gevent pools: use standalone beat instead.
```

Is there any way to use thread execution with Celery beat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do (i.e. embed beat inside the worker) [isn't recommended](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler) anyway. So I'd suggest you start a standalone Celery beat (as adviced by the error message) and worker(s) with gevent pool. The worker's part is where you take advantage of gevent as they execute the I/O bound tasks, not the Celery beat that just kicks them off.

Alternatively, if you use Celery 4.4 or newer, you might try to use [`--pool threads`](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/whatsnew-4.4.html#threaded-tasks-pool) to you threaded task pool.